# how can I connect my localhost to a domaine?

Tags: node.js, dns, server

I have an express server running on my localhost:8080 and is set to display an index.html main webpage. everything is working fine , I just want to know how can I connect it to a domain name that I own. So that once the user hits the domain (lets say its http://example.com) from an external network connection ,  it will direct him to my localhost:8080 main page ?

here is the code which I have running for the server

```
  var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
        url = require('url'),
        fs = require('fs'),
    app.listen(8080);
    // Http handler function
    function handler(req, res) {
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
        if (path == '/') {
            index = fs.readFile(__dirname + '/Index.html', function (error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    res.writeHead(500);
                    return res.end("Error: unable to load live.html");
                }
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                });
                res.end(data);
            });
        } 
    }
```

Comment: how are you plannnig on hosting this, stating that can help us give you a better answer

Comment: for the moment I just want to be able to access the website from a device that is not connected to the network

Comment: Have you Googled `how can I connect my localhost to a domaine?`? There seem to be very useful results there, there's plenty tutorials for how to do this (even though you may need to specify node.js for the node specific configuration settings.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using ngRock. It provides Secure tunnels to localhost
https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

That's a network question, not a programming one. Anyway, you need to edit your DNS zone file and set an A record to point to your localhost's public IP. Then add a routing rule on your router that redirects traffic on port 8080 to your local machine.